# Construct a matrix from existing two other matrices, all with different sizes

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices

```
a = randi ([0 10], 5, 6)
b = randi ([0 10], 2, 45)
```

Now I want to construct a matrix c of size 8 x 15 with all the elements of a and b. Is it possible to do it in a single line code? Some suggestions please.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
a = [1 4 6;
     5 8 0;
     3 7 9;
     4 10 5];

b = [5 6;
     5 0];

c = [1 4 6 5;
     8 0 3 7;
     9 4 10 5;
     5 6 5 0]
```

Comment: How do you want to construct `c`? Should the order of elements in `a` and `b` be preserved?

Comment: So what is the order of the resulting matrix supposed to be? Can you provide an example with smaller matrices and the expected result, for verification?

Comment: `a = [1 4 6;5 8 0;3 7 9;4 10 5],  b = [5 6;5 0],  c = [1 4 6 5;8 0 3 7;9 4 10 5;5 6 5 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications for how to combine `a` and `b` aren't clear. Here is one way to do it.

Create a single column vector built from `a` and `b`. Then `reshape` that column vector into a matrix.

```
c = reshape( [ a(:); b(:) ], 8, 15);
```

This will **only** work if the `numel(a) +  numel(b)` equals the total number of elements in `c`.

Attempts to execute `c = reshape( [ a(:); b(:) ], 7,12);` will **fail** as you aren't providing enough elements to create an `7x12` matrix.

**Update**
Noufal's comment on this answer changes the problem reqs a bit. Basically you stil create the column vector but you only populate C depending on how many elements you have at your disposal:

```
A = rand(5,6);
B = rand(2,45);
C = zeros(8,10);

tmp = [A(:); B(:)]; % create temporary column vector

maxIdx = min( [numel(tmp), numel(C)] ); % determine if tmp or C has fewer elements

C(1:maxIdx) = tmp(1:maxIdx); % fill C from tmp using indices 1:maxIdx
```

Comment: No specification but the numbers should be preserved. Thank you, your answer works. But what will do if size of matrix C is greater or less than that of number of elements in `a` and `b`combined. That is  `c` is like 7 x 12 etc. We can discard the excess elements or add 0 in case of shortage.

Comment: @user1799674, No it won't work. See my update.  In the case that you want to create a `7x12` matrix you will be required to omit values from either `a` or `b`, how do you determine which values to include/omit?

Comment: slayton : once the matrix `c` has get filled up we can omit the rest of elements. Otherwise add zeros afterwards.

Comment: @noufal, and do you want to fill from `a` first?

Comment: `@slayton` First from `a` and then from `b`